# build full url for directory inside webroot in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.4

I'm working in CakePHP 3.4.

I have an image outside `img` directory, in `files` directory under `webroot`

I have a `files` directory inside `webroot` along with `css`, `img`, `js`.

I tried using it like

```
$this->Html->image(WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'myimage.jpg')
```

which is creating path as

```
/var/www/html/myproject/webroot/files/myimage.jpg
```

But this is not showing image. Copying and pasting path in another tab is loading image perfectly. Also, moving image file to `img` directory and using `$this->Html->image('myimage.jpg')` is working fine.

**Why it is not working ?** Also, It is easy to build url for directories `css`, `img` and `js` like

```
// Outputs http://example.com/img/icon.png
$this->Url->image('icon.png', true);
OR
// Outputs /img/icon.png
$this->Url->image('icon.png');
```

which will result as

```
http://example.com/img/icon.png
```

I want to build url for `files` directory like

```
http://example.com/files/myfile.jpg
OR
// /files/myfile.jpg
```

**How to build url for directories other than `img`, `css` and `js`.?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd doubt that using that path as a URL will work, as it's a filesystem path, and that's where the problem is. `HtmlHelper::image()` only supports URLs, relative as well as abolute ones (I guess the docs on this could be improved).

By default relative paths are expected to be relative to the `/img/` folder. In your case you could pass a (web)root-relative path, like:

```
/files/myimage.jpg
```

If you want to generate an absolute URL, use the `fullBase` option:

```
$this->Html->image('/files/myimage.jpg', ['fullBase' => true])
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Html > Linking to Images](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images)**

Comment: can't we create a method under `Html` helper like `$this->Html->file('myfile.jpg`)` which will load file `/webroot/file` directory. Also you are saying to generate absolute path using `$this->Html->image('/files/myimage.jpg')`, what if directory contain other file types like `pdf, mp3, etc`? In my application `files` directory is used to store different file types.

Comment: @AnujTBE Of course you could create an extended helper with a custom method that takes care of all your file handling needs, but that doesn't really have anything to do with your original question. If you need to handle other filetypes as well, then you'd do the same if you use other the existing helpers methods, you'd pass root-relative URLs.